# Return the second element from every pair in list which the first element is in another list

Tags: list, scheme, element

I have a list1 in form ( (1 (8 3)) ( 2(4 5 7)) ( 3 ( 6 7)))

and also I have a list2 in form ( 2 3 )

and I want to have a list with all the second elements from every pair from the list1 where the first element is in list2.

in our case the result will be ( 4 5 7 6 7)

I am thinking smth like this but I am totally confused!

```
  (define (returnlist l1 l2)
  (

   cond(( equal? (map car l1)) (car l2)) (  cdr(car l1)))
         (else  (returnlist  l1 (cdr l2)    )
   )


    ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several steps to this solution:

1. Filter the elements whose key belongs in `list2` (use `filter` for this)
2. Obtain the list corresponding to each key (`map` will be useful)
3. Create a single list with the answer (`apply` + `append` will save the day)

This is what I mean:

```
(define (returnlist l1 l2)
  (apply append                   ; step 3
         (map cadr                ; step 2
              (filter (lambda (e) ; step 1
                        (member (car e) l2))
                      l1))))
```

The result will be as expected:

```
(define list1 '((1 (8 3)) (2(4 5 7)) (3 (6 7))))
(define list2 '(2 3))
(returnlist list1 list2)
=> '(4 5 7 6 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive version:

```
(define (returnlist l1 l2)
  (if (empty? l1)
      '()
      (let* ((c (car l1)) (c1 (car c)))
        (if (member c1 l2)
            (append (cadr c) (returnlist (cdr l1) l2))
            (returnlist (cdr l1) l2)))))
```

then

```
(returnlist '((1 (8 3)) (2 (4 5 7)) (3 (6 7))) '(2 3))
=> '(4 5 7 6 7)
```